# Adding a Curve to a plot

Tags: r, plot, graphics, regression, curve

I want to add a random curve to a plot to test whats fitting best to my data.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(-1.973, -1.685, 2.050, 0.496, 3.310, 2.604, 1.477, 5.552, 2.039, 1.503, 2.171, 1.095),
                 b = c(21,27,36,36,66,53,40,40,65,39,37,32))
lm(b~a,data = df)plot(df$a, df$b, xlab = "a", ylab = "b")
x<-lm(df$b~df$a)$coefficients[1]
curve(x+lm(df$b~df$a)$coefficients[2], add=TRUE, col="red")
```

Though this plot I can draw a regression line (picture) but can I also add a random curve?

[image]

When I run the code, I only see the curve and not the data.
Camn anyone help what I have to do that the data and the curve is visible?
Thanks...

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "random curve". You seem to just be trying to plot the regression line. In this case, you can just use `abline`

```
reg <- lm(b~a,data = df)
plot(df$a, df$b, xlab = "a", ylab = "b")
abline(reg, col="red")
```

[image]
Or if you really wanted to use `curve()`, the `x` variable is special and needs to be able to change. So it would be

```
curve(reg$coefficients[1] + x*reg$coefficients[2], add=TRUE, col="red")
```

Comment: Okay. And is it possible to draw for example a curve x^2 or x^3, log, e^x, or something else (this is what I mean with "random" curve)? Or is it just possible to draw a linear relation?

Comment: Sure, just put in whatever equation you want, but note that after you call `plot()`, the `x` and `y` limits will not change. So if your curve doesn't cross into the plot region, you won't see it.

Comment: Okay, then I think this is my problem. Thank you for your help!